# getiing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

below is a utility created

```
def verifyelementpresence(self, xpath):
    ewait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until
    (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

and used the above utility in the test case

```
print(self.verifyelementpresence("//div[@class='layout pa-3 column']/div[2]").text)
```

when run i am getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

can anyone suggest what is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: From the method `verifyelementpresence` nothing is being returned, i.e. None is returned explicitly and you are trying to access `.text` of the same.

You need to return something from the above method to be able to use `.text`.

Comment: can u help me with syntax.

Comment: Without knowing full details it would be very difficult to say what you want to return, but you can refer to this very nice [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/) on how return works.